# php echo link with variables from database

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Im trying to link to a post with variables from my database, i guess im missing some ' or something... cant get it right it seems. Anyone here that got any idea?

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/conn.php';
try{ 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$server;port=$port","$user","$pass");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE NOT forum_id = 2 ORDER BY topic_id desc";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute ();
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $post) { 
         echo '<a href="http://forum.mysite.com/viewtopic.php?f='.$post[forum_id].'&t='.$post[topic_id].'">', $post[subject], '</a>';
    }
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$conn=null;
?>
```

This is the problem:

```
echo '<a href="http://forum.mysite.com/viewtopic.php? f='.$post[forum_id].'&t='.$post[topic_id].'">', $post[subject], '</a>';
```

the link should look something like this:
`http://forum.mysite.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=12`

Comment: And what is the link it is giving...?

Comment: You have an extra space between `?` and `f=`.

Comment: it is just blank :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use . for concatenation (not comma)

```
echo '<a href="http://forum.mysite.com/viewtopic.php?f='. 
  $post[forum_id].'&t='.$post[topic_id].'">' .  
      $post[subject]  .'</a>';
```

and remove the blank between  ? and f

Comment: are you sure you have proper value  in the the vars ... update the your question and show the actual result using var_dump('<a href="http://forum.mysite.com/viewtopic.php? f='. 
  $post[forum_id].'&t='.$post[topic_id].'">' .  
      $post[subject]  .'</a>')

Comment: comma can be used to separate multiple arguments to `echo`.

Comment: sigh... subject shou've been post_subject /facepalm

Comment: @perkällström  what in var_dump ?.. update your question and show me .. the result